# Boolean "or" operator doesn't return correct result for if choice != "y" or choice != "yes":

Tags: python, operators

When a user enters "yes" or "y" it should continue the loop. However the `or` operator doesn't seem to be working in this case. Does anybody know why? If I type in "y" or "yes" the loop breaks and ends the program.

```
 choice = input("View another product?: ").lower()
 if choice != "y" or choice != "yes":
    print("Bye") 
    break
```

Comment: `choice != 'y' or choice != 'yes'` is **always** true, even if `choice == 'y'` or `choice == 'yes'`. Think about it for a minute.

Comment: (because if `choice != 'y'` is false, then `choice != 'yes'` will be true, and `False or True` is `True`).

Comment: You should use `and` here, or even better, do a list containment check: `if not choice in ["y", "yes"]`

Comment: TIL there is a canonical duplicate for this. It's really mind-boggling how difficult I find it to get those to turn up in the search sometimes. :/

Comment: @Programmer, I'd suggest a tuple rather than a list. Cheaper to construct since they can be interned, whereas even with a literal list the runtime needs to build a new instance each time in case it might get mutated later.

Comment: Also `not in`, like this: `if choice not in ("y", "yes")`